# IOptions pattern with default dynamic value not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a class which contains my configuration of a `StartDate` string, it is a `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss` representation of a timestamp, this string can be passed through appsettings or environment variables as normal with ASP.NET applications, but when it is not set, I would like it to return the current time.

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
}
```

In my Startup I register this configuration class like so:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I then inject it in another service and use it like so:

```cs
public class SomeOtherService
{
    private readonly MyOptions _options;
    public SomeOtherService(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }
    
    void SomeFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"StartDate is: {_options.StartDate}");
    }
}
```

My AppSettings(.Development).json nor environment variables contain a value for `MyOptions.StartDate`

Whenever I call `SomeOtherClass.SomeFunction()`, it will keep returning whatever the timestamp was when my app first started.

I have split the `StartDate` property in `MyOptions` into a separate getter and setter class, and noticed the setter is being hit while the application starts. It seems it's reading the initial return value from `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")`, but then setting this value, causing the set value to returned in any consecutive get call.

What am I missing to get it to return the current timestamp whenever it is called?

Comment: Create a function on your options class, and access your start date through that function, with your null check of course. Your property is only going to be initialized when your app starts, it will not do what you are wanting it to do.  If the setting in your file is something you expect to change on the fly, you might consider injecting IOptionsMonitor<T> or IOptionsSnapshot.  Check out the docs, there is alot of good info there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the code like below

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(_ => Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(_));
```

the `appsettings.json` should have `MyOptions` element like below

```
"MyOptions": {"StartDate": "test"}
```

Please check that environment name matches with environment specific appsettings if you are modifying not the global `appsettings.json` file.
It means that environment name have to be `Development` if `appsettings.Development.json` has `MyOptions` configuration element.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I get the same error when trying it like this :(

Comment: @Alex I've just checked `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));` and found that it works too. Probably you have not set `MyOptions` in the `appsettings` file (or set it in wrong environment file). Please find my answer updated.